# How to simulate a prior for a Poisson distribution?

Tags: r, distributions, bayesian, gamma-distribution

I would like to simulate random variates from a Poisson distribution to act as prior for a predictive model, but I fail to do it correctly.

Here is my attempt:

```
prior <- dgamma(1000, 2.6, 1.07)
predictive.prior <- rpois(1000,prior) 
barplot(table(predictive.prior)/1000)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only about a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Change dgamma to rgamma:

```
prior <- rgamma(1000, 2.6, 1.07)
```